# C#, Selenium, PhantomJS adding CLI args for disabling ssl/web security with RemoteWebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, phantomjs, remotewebdriver

Have tried:

1.

```
capabilities.SetCapability("phantomjs.cli.args", "[\"--web-security=false\"]");
```

2.

```
capabilities.SetCapability("phantomjs.cli.args", 
                "['--ssl-protocol=tlsv1','--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--web-security=false']");
```

Also with escaped `\"` instead of `'`.

Now I'm looking into using this service thing, but I'm not sure how to pass it to the RemoteWebDriver constructor (like you do in firefox' case `capabilities.SetCapability(FirefoxDriver.ProfileCapabilityName, profile);`
or

```
FirefoxOptions x = new FirefoxOptions();
x.ToCapabilities()
```

So this is where I'm at:

```
PhantomJSDriverService service = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.IgnoreSslErrors = true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way to do away with all the fuss is to use:

```
capabilities.SetCapability("phantomjs.cli.args", 
                new String[] { "--web-security=no", "--ssl-protocol=tlsv1", "--ignore-ssl-errors=true" });
```

This solved it and now PhantomJS bypasses the bad certificate.